# PHP include/require method with unwanted refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, stored-procedures

It is not about login form or something similar. The application already running secured session. It is about internal task for updating particular data.
As part of application, I create one main file which include another php file using the php include method. The included file represents a framework for including of a form selected from many possible forms. Selection is performed using anchor tag in side menu, which is dynamically created using js and php from MySQL database.

```
//path for mainfile.php: /ThemeDir/SecuredDir/workDir/mainfile.php
mainfile.php
….
<nav class=”side-menu”> 
    <ul>
        <li class=”sub-menu”> <a id=”dir-path” href=”#”></a> 
            <ul>
                <li class=”anchor”>
                    <a href=”#form-name”>
                    <span id=”form-label”>form-label</span></a>
</li></ul></li></ul></nav>
....
<div id="uso"><?php include("../formsDir/mainframe.php"); ?></div>
<div id="hddForm" style="display: none">
    <form id='obrForm' action="" metod = "post" role="form" name="obrForm">
        <input type="text" id="incPath" name="incPath" value="" />
     </form>
 </div>
….
Mainfile.js
$(document).ready(function() {
….
    $(". anchor > a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fname = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#+/, '');
        var dir = $(". sub-menu a").attr("id");
        var incPath = dir + "/" + fname + ".php";  //path to form-name.php
        document.getElementById("incPath").value = incPath; // parse data
        submitIfFormComplete()
        function submitIfFormComplete(){ // submiting a form ‘obrForm’
            var tag = document.forms[0].getAttribute("id");
            if (document.getElementById('incPath').value !== ""){
                document.getElementById(tag).submit();
                alert('submited');
            }else{alert('shit submited');}
        }
    });
….
});
//path for mainframe.php: /ThemeDir/SecuredDir/formsDir/mainFrame.php
mainframe.php
<meta charset="utf-8">
….
<div id="inc-div">
    <?php
        If (isset($_GET["incPath"])){
            $incPath = filter_var($_REQUEST["incPath"], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            include $incPath; //same result w or w/o echo
            //path: /ThemeDir/SecuredDir/formsDir/sub-formsDir/form-name.php
        }else{
            echo "SHIT POST";
        }
    ?>
</div>
….
```

So far so good. Until now it works as it's supposed to work. The problem appears when form is invoked, first looks as it should, but for a split of second disappears, so that the mainfile.php with included mainframe.php returns to its starting condition. It is obvious that the last procedure involves refreshing the file, and because most are mainly dynamically created procedures, everything are returned to the initial state. I checked all the procedures relating to this part of the application and nothing affects this problem. In all steps i have a procedure to intercept errors, but no errors  registered. I could not find similar or identical problem around the forums on the web. I hope that this behavior has a solution so any advice will help me a lot.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. Unless you use AJAX to submit this is expected behavior and how submit process works. If you want to populate the form values again you need to do that before you send it back to browser.

Comment: @charlietflNeither I am not quite sure what I expected, but previously tried by Ajax XMLHttpRequest to submitt form and repeatedly got error. Unable to fix I tried the other way, but obviously the wrong way. Now I reviewed the previous procedure again and get the same mistake! Namely, the procedure goes completely executed using XMLHttpRequest up to end "html.send (null);", whether it fulfills the requirement "if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {...} else { ...} "or not I certainly get " 404 not Found ".

Comment: I also tried immediately after the "xml = new XMLHttpRequest ();" to set up that first check if the file exists with "xml.open ( 'HEAD', filePath, true); xml.send (); if (xml.status! ==" 404 ") {... perform html.open ( 'GET' ...) ... up to xml.send (null);} ", but again with a 404 error, the procedure completely passes through the Ajax request and again I get the error indicated on “xml.send (null);”, thus interrupt other actions! I also tried with a new instance of XMLHttpRequest to check whether a file exists and then execute "xml.open ...", but the result is the same again!

Comment: I am indeed grateful for your comments, and certainly much would help me if you have ideas how to overcome this. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: since you are using jQuery much simpler to use `$.ajax` which also has error handling built in. 404 means the url can't be found so it is incorrect. Use your browser dev tools network to look at what actual url browser is using and adjust accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl Finally, taking in mind your advice, successful with a very simple procedure: "$.ajax (" path / to / file.php ").done (function () {file exist}).fail (function () {file does not exist}); " which forwards strict conditions. Poorly expressed about "404" actually used the combined terms "UNSENT" for xml.statusText and "0" for xml.status, to avoid HTML eror "404". I apologize for this.

Comment: Also I apologize for my lack of knowledge in this area, but I worked more than 20 years exclusively on programs such as VB, VBA and MS SQL for use mainly in MS Access, where the procedures and in particular the conditions are defined strictly and without exceptions. Since previous work for me became quite tedious, about half a year, I decided to try myself in web design that immediately caught my attention. I am very grateful to you for your advice.

Comment: click F12 while browser open and look at network tab. Need to fix that 404 path and seeing actual url used will help see why it's not right.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I constantly doing that, and allwais says: name: selected-file.php; status: 404; Type: xhr; initiator: 
jquery.min.js:4; and so.This is no longer affects the client side.I was just wondering why the message appears and interrupts the code once it has condition!File does not exist really, and now overall code works as expected with files that exist.I will create files further, but now i am in performing a test to intercept of error if there is no file.Again i have to revise the entire code, possibly a function or procedure depends on file that not yet been created, what I dont believe, but..

Comment: I posted a question about the same problem after I have made changes based on your advice but still appears a strange problem I can not solve it. Appreciating your reputation if you have enough patience would be grateful for your contribution.link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964916/php-include-require-method-with-variable-path?noredirect=1#comment67209678_39964916