# PHP include/require method with variable path

Tags: javascript, php, html

Someone to help where I'm wrong! Ajax returns correct information. It also shows on 'success' include page with all data in 'alert(html)'. Echo $idName; and echo $path; print correct information in carrier page (where is the code). There is no side refreshments in the page. Require method does not block the page. The problem is that div include remains empty! Thanks.

```
<div id="include">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['idName1'])) {
            $idName = $_POST['idName1'];
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT in_path FROM strani WHERE id_name='$idName '");
            $row_path = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $path = $row_path['in_path'];
            require($path); /*Also tried: require(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path); all the same!*/
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Because what I want to explain further, it will not pass like a comment, I declare to edit the question. Attach the file structure and directories, as well as code that changed to shorten the procedure, in order to reveal the error. The predicted scenario is as follows: authorized associate since will log in, will open the main-page.php with optional menu of forms that are allowed to edit. This page immediately include ‘form-carrier.php with it self include some-data.php’. Once through anchor tag he will choose the appropriate form, this form should be included in the appropriate div with “id=include”.

```
Page structure:
    main-page.php > It includes file: require(form-carrier.php) which iclude: require(form.php); and: require(some-data.php); 
Dir structure:
    secured-dir (It contains files: login.php; error.php; error-log)
        styles-dir
        js-dir
        includes-dir (It contains files: functions.php; db-conn-conf.php; process-login-logout.php; session-class.php; error-log)
        forms-dir (It contains files: form-carrier.php; some-data-php; error_log)
            forms-byclass1-subdir (It contains files: form-some-name.php; error_log)
            forms-byclass2-subdir (It contains files: form-some-name.php; error_log)
            ..... other sub dirs....
        working-dir It contains files: (main-page.php; error_log)
```

Tested by specifying the path by typing, and discovered that it works properly if inscribe in require(“forms-byclass1-subdir/form-some-name.php”); as well as “../forms-dir/ forms-byclass1-subdir/ form-some-name.php”. This leads me to the conclusion that the "form-some-name.php" is registered by the main-page.php which is in working-dir, as well as by form-carrier.php located in forms-dir, which is a child of main- page.php. Not supposed to work like this, but it works. To avoid confusion I replaced two including files (form-carrier.php; and some-data-php) in same dir “working-dir” together with “main-page.php”.

```
Now dir structure look like:
forms-dir (only error_log)
    forms-byclass1-subdir (It contains files: form-some-name.php; error_log)
    ..... others forms-byclass-subdirs....
working-dir It contains files: (main-page.php; form-carrier.php; some-data-php; error_log)

And the php code in form-carrier.php:
...
<div id="include">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['strPath1'])) {
            $strPath = $_POST['strPath1'];
            var_dump($strPath);
            require($strPath); 
        }
    ?>
</div>
...
```

I shortened the code and decided not to go through the data base, but in javascript create variable with the full path and send it directly by AJAX to the target file.  Again the result is the same. If inscribe the path by typing, the code is executed correctly, if I go with use of a variable in javascript, sent by Ajax, I get correct data, in alert(html) can read all data from the form-some-name.php, as well as form-carrier.php; and some-data.php, var_dump($strPath); gives me the correct path, but include div is still empty! I will be very grateful if anyone still interested  contribute to solving this, for me unknown and strange problem.

Comment: Are you saying that `echo $path` instead of `require($path)` inside the `if` condition outputs the correct path?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($_POST)`  and $path to see there populated with anything?

Comment: Where are your PHP files located?

Comment: Yes it outputs correct path and is a same as require($path), Ajax would otherwise not returned correct answer on success, meaning it shows complete content of included page, not only success msg. Therefore i use require method instead of include, which block the page if has not correct path. Also are not registered any of errors across the application. Just it not showing in the specified div. PHP include files are in sub dir of carrier page, and stored in database.

Comment: echo var_dump($_POST) 'returning string(9) name_form', which is correct string for WERE condition. And  mysqli_fetch_array($query); returns correct pat.

Comment: Correct "var_dump($_POST)" echo  "array(1){['idName1']=>string(9) name_form}"

Comment: I edit the question, so if you're still willing to help I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one with sufficient knowledge, wants to spend time on solving this problem, and I am sure that is easily solvable, I solved for now and post hoping to find useful for other beginners in this area as me! I went back to the first approach. This way is much simpler and provides few following steps: page1 achor click>page1 js var for path and asign to intermediate filed in page1>js load page3 in page2 with filePath. The problem with premature refreshing fixed as follows: first with splitting JS file where were all the codes for those three files, in three for each page separately, also adding setTimeout function to the other procedures for executing with correct order. Now it’s running smoothly!

```
main-page.php
<nav class=”side-menu”>
…
    <?php ... Creating a side-menu from database MySQL ... ?>
// echo resault:
<ul>
    <li class=”sub-menu”><a id=”forms-byclass1-subdir” href=”#”></a> 
        <ul>
            <li class=”anchor”>
                <a href=”# form-some-name”>
                    <span id=”form-header”>form-label</span></a>
</li></ul></li></ul></nav>
…
</nav>
…
<div id="fc">
    <?php require("form-carrier.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id=”hidden”
    <input type="text" id="path" name="path" value=”” />
</div>
…
form-carrier.php
…
<div id="include"></div> 
…
Main-page.js
…
$(".sub-menu > a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    … variables to get a desired path …
    $("#include").load(path);
    setTimeout(function() {
        … other procedures …
    }, 60);
});
```

This does not mean that I was gave up from approach, using Ajax,  PHP and db, but until I find the way to fix it, this is certainly a good solution. Therefore remains the call for contribution from the gurus of web-design.

**Note for proper functioning various events:** because the file is dynamically included , will be problematic using of JQuery .click (), as well as JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener if it not used in html inline. The most reliable way, at least in my case, is using of Jquery “.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )”.